# 1B6 error while trying to create an XML map in Excel

Tags: xml, excel, export-to-xml

When trying to create a XML map in excel I get the error 1B6:
(Add-Ins Tab -> XML Tools -> Select Convert range to XML -> click OK button)

```
fnMapRangeWithXml window which states
```

> ```
>  ERROR 1B6: Object doesn't support this property or method
> ```

I have saved it before as an XML from excel, and had gotten any errors.

*Relevant for both 2007 and 2010 version of Excel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. In the Add-Ins tab in Excel.

   Select XML Tools -> Select Convert range to XML List ->
   Change the range which was selected -> click OK button

   Do this again (Add-Ins -> XML Tools -> Convert to XML)

   This time select the range you actually need 
   Click OK. 
   This should resolve the error.
2. Another option is to copy the worksheet to another worksheet and then map from the new worksheet.